# Parsing @Context UriInfo to java thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jax-rs, runnable, java-threads

I'm trying to parse `@Context UriInfo` to another thread and do some task. But when i try to run it, it gives the error as

```
Exception in thread "Thread-691" org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo
```

My code as follows

```
@GET
@Path("/thread")

public void thread(@Context UriInfo url){


Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>> " + url.getRequestUri().getQuery());
    }
};

Thread t = new Thread(run);

t.start();
```

}

How can I get the UriInfo to the new thread?

Comment: Does anyone don't know about that issue?

Comment: You should not start your own threads in an jee container. It seems that you are using jboss / wildfly. The application server mangaes the threads by itself. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to send multiple post request from the JBOSS to other server.

Comment: But why in a separate thread?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the UriInfo parameter final and you will be able to access it from your run() method.

```
public void thread(@Context final UriInfo url){
```

I've no idea what you are actually trying to achieve here though. I doubt you actually want to do this.

Comment: Already did. But no luck. I met with this error as before.


Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool-8-worker-1" org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo