# Injected variable pass to new thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, jax-rs

I want to pass the injected variable to the new thread. My question is directly related to the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42649287/parsing-context-uriinfo-to-java-thread). Above question's problem is @Contex is located in another thread and my code is running in new thread. So I want to pass the Injected `UriInfo` to another thread.

Comment: Can you make a class that implements runnable with a constructor that takes an UriInfo?

Comment: Same results and same error

Comment: What error is that? How is this question different from the other one?